# Using Array to Identify Div in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to build a jquery validation function.  I want to first declare an array on keydown, and then run a function on keyup.  However the function does not seem to be working.  Following is my html and jquery.

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="user_name" />
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var validatearray = [];

    $("#user_name").keydown(function() { 
        validatearray = ["#user_name", "t", "5", "50", "alpha", "Name", "#errormsg1"];  
    });

    /* ----------------- Define Validate Function */

    var validate1 = function()
    {
        alert("its working");
    }

    $(validatearray[0]).on('keyup', validate1); 


});
```

when i do `$("#user_name").on('keyup', validate1);` then it works

Answer (score 0):

It is issue relating to your variable scope. When you declare your variable inside a function here `validatearray`, it cannot be called from outside function ([read here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)).

You have to define your `validatearray` out side of function, then it should works. here fix ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6fp9w3y/))

Answer (score 0):

When JQuery is initialized, validatearray has no elements and hence it is not able to add a 'keyup' listener to validatearray[0].  In your code, you add elements to the array inside the keydown event.

I have not tested this code, but I think the following should work.

```
$("#user_name").keydown(function() { 
    validatearray = ["#user_name", "t", "5", "50", "alpha", "Name", 
        "#errormsg1"];  
    $(validatearray[0]).on('keyup', validate1);
    });
```

The problem with this is, it will add a keyup listener to your DOM element every time keydown fires.  You can workaround that by having this wrapped inside some condition so that you don't add listener more than once.

You can add a class to your input element and add a listener to the class which should work.

```
<input type="text" class="FirstName" id="user_name" />
```

and then

```
$('.FirstName').on('keyup', validate1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working

**Jquery**

```
var validatearray = [];

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#user_name").keydown(function() { 
        validatearray = ["#user_name", "t", "5", "50", "alpha", "Name", "#errormsg1"]; 
    });
});

/* ----------------- Define Validate Function */
var validate1 = function()
{
    if ($(validatearray[0]).val().length < validatearray[2] || $(validatearray[0]).val().length > validatearray[3])
    { 
        $(validatearray[6]).html(validatearray[5]+" : "+validatearray[2]+"-"+validatearray[3]+" Characters") 
    } 
}
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="user_name" onkeyup="validate1()/>
```

But I'll be running into problems in future because some text fields will have autocomplete functions running on keyup also.. but that is for later...